# Network card/driver stops under heavy load

Tags: networking, windows-7

Since about approx. 2 month, I do have the following issue with my approx. 1 year old development machine (Windows 7, 64 bit):

When doing network intensive operations, like e.g. executing some SQL script on a remote SQL server to select or update 1000 of records, **the network card stops working**.

I.e. suddenly, No network connection is present anymore. No internet, no local connection, simply nothing.

The only resolution so far I found is to disable my network card and then simply enable it back, like in the following screenshots:

1.) Click "Deactivate"

[image]

2.) Click "Activate"

[image]

*(German screenshots only, sorry)*

Now this is an acceptable solution to work around this issue, but I would love to have this fixed, since it suddenly stops me from working when I'm connected remotely via VPN/RDP on my machine (Win7 64bit).

So my question is:

**Could you imagine a possible cause for this issue and give some hints how to hunt/resolve it?**

I could imagine that this is a driver issue, a hardware issue or even some kind of background software issue like a software firewall or a virus scanner.

**Edit:**

Since I still was unable to find the reason, I did some research and put together a simple script to automatically disable and re-enable the network interface card (NIC):

```
@REM =============================================
@REM Restarts the NIC if a ping is unsucessful.
@REM
@REM See http://bit.ly/disable-enable-nic-batch
@REM
@REM To find out NIC number, use "wmic nic get name, index" 
@REM once and change it. In this file below, it is "7".
@REM
@REM Written 2011-01-23 by Uwe Keim.
@REM =============================================

@cls

ping www.google.com | find "Bytes="
if errorlevel 1 goto :mustrestart

@echo ---NOT RESTARTING NIC.
goto :eof

:mustrestart

@echo ---RESTARTING NIC.
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable

:eof
```

I let Windows Task Scheduler call this script every 10 minutes and have a temporary workaround for my “broken” NIC.

**Edit 2011-04-16:**

The error persisted even after completely installing a fresh Windows.

I then bought a new network interface card (the original was an on-board "card") and the error went away ever since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would point to drivers/hardware issue, try to update the card drivers.

Comment: Do you see any reason why this happens rather suddenly and did not always behave this way from the very beginning?

Comment: Anything changed ? Windows could have updated the card drivers, hardware could have some physical problem.. Check the event viewer logs when the network go down for further information.